# c# is adding "this" optional within a class method

Tags: c#

I have a class for an object that looks like this:

```
public class SomeObject
{
   int SomeInt { get; set; }

   public void SomeMethod()
   {
       var SomeVar = this.SomeInt;
       var SomeVar2 = SomeInt;
   }
}
```

When I'm referring to a class property within a class method, does it make the code better/faster/safer if I write `this.SomeInt` instead of `SomeInt` like I do when I assign `SomeVar2`?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: There's no difference after compilation. It's just a matter of readability/coding practices.

Comment: It's a good practise because you eliminate ambiguity, which leads to programming errors, sometimes. I dont know if it has an impact on speed but if it does, it will be worthless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't affect the output, as the MSIL is the same.

I "might" be safer, if you don't have any variable naming convention that differs class variables from local variables.

Answer (score 2):

using "this." does not change how the code is generated.  Thus, performance and safety is not affected.  Whether or not you include "this." when you don't have to, is a matter of style.  Some style guidelines suggest using "this." always on members.

Answer (score 2):

Some examples of times when you may need to add 'this' is when you have a local-scope variable in the same scope (which Resharper or VS, I forget which, should notify you of), like:

```
string name;
void SetName(string name)
{
     this.name = name;
}
```

Or if you're deriving a constructor from another for some reason:

```
public void Person(string Name, int age) : this(age)
{
}
public void Person(int age)
{
}
```

Otherwise, it's doesn't have any effect the compilation, but I still occasionally use it to explicitly differentiate between fields and parameters when they might be confusing, etc.

Comment: Another few scenarios: calling an extension method on the local instance requires `this.TheMethod()`, as does ctor-chaining, and passing a reference to the instance outside of the class. Or replacing a struct in its entirety. The first is perhaps the most interesting.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no difference at compile time. As few have suggested above that it makes your code more readable, but I think it just another way of accessing your class variable.