# How to understand "this" keyword in flex

Tags: apache-flex, this

It seems stackoverflow ignores `this` keyword when searching.

It seems the `this` keyword in flex is different from JavaScript's. I feel it similar with Java's, but not sure.

How to understand it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` can be a bit confusing for newcomers to MXML. In MXML `this` is the current "root tag" not the tag you are attaching an eventlistener to, or giving some databinding.

Even so it might be a bit confusing at first, if you think about it it makes perfect sense as an MXML file basically compiles down to a single .as3 class which `this` referes to.

Answer (score 0):

In AS3, `this` is the same as in Java, the reference to the current object.

Answer (score 0):

"this" works same as it works in Java or C#. If you are familiar with C#, this link might help [c# is adding "this" optional within a class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593697/c-sharp-is-adding-this-optional-within-a-class-method)